# grails 3.1.10 with spring boot 1.4.0.RELEASE is throwing Failed to instantiate ch.qos.logback

Tags: grails, grails3

We are upgrading grails version 3.0.9 to 3.1.10 with spring boot 1.4.0.RELEASE and when i try to compile i am getting this error:

```
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader.getResourceOccurrenceCount(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.multiplicityWarning(ContextInitializer.java:173)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.statusOnResourceSearch(ContextInitializer.java:196)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.getResource(ContextInitializer.java:143)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.findURLOfDefaultConfigurationFile(ContextInitializer.java:127)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:140)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:119)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:328)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:280)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:290)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$getLog.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at ciab.base.Application.<clinit>(Application.groovy)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:383)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:237)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.<init>(GrailsApp.groovy)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:363)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)    
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetConstructor(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:524)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:407)
    ... 12 more
```

Any idea what went wrong and i tried to exclude the logback-core but no luck. Please let me know for any fix.

Thanks
Sri

Answer (score 0):

Grails 3.1.x is compatible with Spring Boot 1.3.x

To use Spring Boot 1.4.x you need to use Grails 3.2.x which is nearing release, but at the milestone stage as of this writing.